# virtual env does not activate

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I tried to open a virtual env using a bash script but I get this error :

```
./training_corpus1.sh: line 8: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

The bash script looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

cd /home/ge/ke/anaconda3/envs 

source env/bin/activate

cd ~/eXP/bert

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python training.py \
    --exp_name bert \ ...
```

env directory looks like this :

```
(env) ke@dere2:~/anaconda3/envs$ ls
env  myenv
(env) ke@dere2:~/anaconda3/envs$ cd env

(env) ke@dere2:~/anaconda3/envs/env$ ls

bin              etc      man          qml        ssl
compiler_compat  include  mkspecs      resources  translations
conda-meta       lib      phrasebooks  sbin       var
doc              libexec  plugins      share      x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
(env) ke@dere2:~/anaconda3/envs/env$ cd bin
(env) ke@dere2:~/anaconda3/envs/env/bin$ ls
2to3                                fribidi                      jupyter-kernelspec                 pyami_sendmail           saved_model_cli
2to3-3.6                            futurize                     jupyter-lab                        pybabel
```

Comment: as you can see, there is no `activate` file in the `bin` dir

Comment: I use conda to create this environment should I recreate it ?

Comment: might be an idea

Comment: There's no need to change directories, as you switch to `cd ~/eXP/bert` immediately. `source /home/ge/ke/anaconda/envs/env/bin/activate` would be sufficient.

Comment: @ chepner ./training_corpus1.sh: line 5: /home/ge/ke/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/activate: No such file or directory give me this error

Comment: @tuergeist but why do the activate file does not appear ?

Comment: @kely789456123 no clue. What command do you run?

Comment: this one : set -e

cd /home/ge/ke/anaconda3/envs 

source env/bin/activate

cd ~/eXP/bert

Comment: What OS are you using, and which version of Conda?

Comment: @AMC I found the pb , thank you